# SQL summing with WHERE condition based on distinct values

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following table, lets call this table_a:

| Zone | vehicle_name | vehicle_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | BusA1 | Start |
| A | BusA2 | Start |
| A | BusA3 | Stopped |
| B | BoatB1 | Ready |
| B | BoatB2 | Stopped |
| B | BoatB3 | Start |
| C | CarC1 | Ready |
| C | CarC2 | Ready |
| C | CarC3 | Stopped |

I would like to create a new table from the table_a :

| Zone | no_of_vehicle | no_of_start | no_of_ready | no_of_stopped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 |

What would be the most efficient way to this?

E.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ZONE) AS ZONE,
       SUM(IF ZONE = 'A' THEN ... IF ZONE = 'B' THEN ...
FROM table_a
```

Comment: `SELECT .. SUM(vehicle_status = 'Start') AS no_of_start, .. GROUP BY Zone ..`

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `SELECT DISTINCT` gives you distinct _rows_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT ZONE AS ZONE, ...` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  Zone,
  COUNT(DISTINCT vehicle_name) AS no_of_vehicle,
  SUM(vehicle_status = 'Start') AS no_of_start,
  SUM(vehicle_status = 'Ready') AS no_of_ready,
  SUM(vehicle_status = 'Stopped') AS no_of_stopped
FROM table_a
GROUP BY Zone;
```

This single SQL query achieves the desired result using conditional aggregation and grouping by the 'Zone'.

Comment: @user19192927: And `SUM( <condition> )`works, because in MySQL true=1, false=0. So adding up the expressions, means counting the condition matches.

Comment: And `SUM(case when vehicle_status = 'Start' then 1 else 0 end)` is the portable, standard compliant way.

Comment: And `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE vehicle_status = 'Start')` is the *unportable* standard compliant way, because most DBMS still don't support this syntax yet (among them: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle). A pity. I like this syntax for its readability.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I like it too. However, an _optional_ feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Zone,
    COUNT(vehicle_name) AS no_of_vehicle,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vehicle_status = 'Start' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_of_start,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vehicle_status = 'Ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_of_ready,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vehicle_status = 'Stopped' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no_of_stopped
FROM
    table_a
GROUP BY
    Zone;
```